# KVM Virtual Machine Manager Shared Folder Mount Error

Tags: mount, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've created an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop VM inside Fedora using Virtual Machine Manager. I'm trying to mount a host directory in the guest OS but it's not working. I used the instructions provided here: http://troglobit.com/blog/2013/07/05/file-system-pass-through-in-kvm-slash-qemu-slash-libvirt/

I use the following mount command in the Ubuntu guest:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L /vmshare /home/williaw/rh
```

And get the following error which makes absolutely no sense to me and I have no idea how to fix:

```
mount: /home/williaw/rh: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you double check if the module is/can be loaded: `sudo modprobe 9p`
Also check this (afterwars) `cat /proc/filesystems | grep 9p` it should report `nodev   9p`

Comment: I could fixed it by using virtio-9p instead of virtiofs.